# Siproxd as "middle-man" fails

Tags: proxy, sip

I'm running Kamailio SIP server on one server. It works fine with SIP clients etc.

Now I'm trying to run Siproxd SIP Proxy on another server.

I've installed Siproxd and calling netstat -tulpn | grep 5060 shows:

tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5060 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 22216/siproxd

udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5060 0.0.0.0:* 22216/siproxd

So it is running.

But when I try to connect clients to my original Kamailio SIP server with the server IP from the one running Siproxd as proxy, it fails.

Can anyone help my out debug the problem?

And shouldn't this solution, when it works, make my clients looks as if they come from the IP of the server running Siproxd?

Answer (score 0):

Get familiar with Wireshark.

It looks daunting at first, but especially for text based protocols like SIP or HTTP you'll only ever need to start a capture by clicking on the pseudo-interface "any", do a connection attempt, pick a packet that goes to 5060, right click on that and choose "follow TCP stream".

Tell us how exactly it fails and we'll go from there.

Comment: I'm familiar with Wireshark and that is what I used to find the problem with Siproxd not adding the IP of the server it's running on.

When it worked it added:

VIA: ORIGINAL IP ADDRESS

VIA: IP ADDRESS OF THE SERVER RUNNING SIPROXD

Now it only adds:

VIA: ORIGINAL IP ADDRESS

Comment: The first via: header should be supplied by the UAC initiating the request. I am interpreting your above comment as the proxy not adding anything to the via: chain. Are you sure the request is in fact traversing the proxy, and not sent directly by the UAC to the UAS?